# IIS 7.5 Handling 500 Errors Differently Than IIS 6.0

Tags: web-services, http, asp-classic, iis-6, iis-7.5

Our Classic ASP application contains a web service that can be called over an HTTP. POST or GET.  The web service does its duty and then writes out, using Response.Write, an XML message over HTTP.

Here is an example.

```
Response.ContentType = "text/xml"
Response.Status      = "500 Error"
Response.Write("<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>")
Response.Write("<PeelMe>")
Response.Write("<Error>Your orange was actually blue!</Error>")
Response.Write("</PeelMe>")
```

When the application was hosted in IIS 6.0, the caller received the XML and was able to parse it just fine.

Then, we switched to IIS 7.5.

As in IIS 6.0, we set up a customer error page, let's call it "Blah.asp", to render certain custom text to the browser when an error occurred while an actual user was browsing the site.  When we switched to IIS 7.5, all 500 error messages written out to the web service caller were now captured by IIS 7.5, redirecting the thread to Blah.asp and subsequently writing the HTML of Blah.asp back to the caller.

Here is my question:

How do I get IIS 7.5 to act like IIS 6.0 so that when I want to write out a 500 Error message back to a web service caller, I can do that, without IIS 7.5's custom error handling getting in the way?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try setting the app pool to asp classic? We've been doing a lot of upgrades lately; constantly running into issues with 7.5.

Setting the app pool back, resolves probably 80% of our issues.

Comment: Our systems guru answers your question by saying:

"App Pools are set to 'Integrated' because 'Classic' was causing the ASP.NET part to not work. My understanding is that that setting does not affect Classic ASP, just ASP.NET applications."

Answer (score 0):

Since IIS7 the web.config offers more options. You could try the following to get the bevaviour you are after:

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors errorMode="Detailed">
        <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode="-1" />
        <error statusCode="500" prefixLanguageFilePath="" path="/[CUSTOMERRORPAGE].asp" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
    </httpErrors>
</system.webServer>
```